# How to make this white square appear at centre by default instead of top upper-left hand corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this jsfiddle where the white square always appear at the top upper-left hand corner.

http://jsfiddle.net/helpme128/3kwwo53t/2/

I want to make the white square appear at the centre instead.

I tried to make the code change below (`x = 150, y = 150`);

```
.directive('ngDraggable', function($document) {   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dragOptions: '=ngDraggable'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var startX, startY, x = 150, y = 150,
          start, stop, drag, container;
```

However, it did not work. What should be the right code to get the white square to appear at the centre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is have the white square start out at a certain position, then give it the position in the stylesheet.

```css
left: 130px;
top: 130px;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3kwwo53t/6/

The JavaScript is used for dragging, not for defining the initial status.

By the way, it's 130px, not 150. Since the outer div is 300px across, and the inner square measures 40px, its offset needs to be -20px from the center.

Edit: or, if you want to be independent of the size of the container, set the container's `position` to `relative` and calculate the position like this:

```css
left: calc(50% - 20px);
top: calc(50% - 20px);
```

Newer fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3kwwo53t/7/

Be aware though that only modern browsers support `calc`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if you don't want to hard code pixels,

```
#container {
   width : 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: black;
   display:table-cell;    
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center;
}

.shape {
    width : 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Try this link - https://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/8/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include the margins and therefore looks like the OP's one. And it makes my browser complain about mixing http with https content. Also, if I put this CSS in a working fiddle, it stops working.

Comment: Try this link - https://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/8/. Seems like something wrong, press RUN button again.

Comment: Still the same problem: warnings about insecure information, and you can't drag the square.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setPosition()` in the link function after everything is set up:

```
.directive('ngDraggable', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dragOptions: '=ngDraggable'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      var startX, startY, x = 150, y = 150,
          start, stop, drag, container;

      var width  = elem[0].offsetWidth,
          height = elem[0].offsetHeight;

      // Obtain drag options
      if (scope.dragOptions) {
        start  = scope.dragOptions.start;
        drag   = scope.dragOptions.drag;
        stop   = scope.dragOptions.stop;
        var id = scope.dragOptions.container;
        if (id) {
            container = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
        }
      }

      // Bind mousedown event
      elem.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        startX = e.clientX - elem[0].offsetLeft;
        startY = e.clientY - elem[0].offsetTop;
        $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        if (start) start(e);
      });

      # The position of the element is not changed until the `setPosition` function 
      # is called
      setPosition()

      // Handle drag event
      function mousemove(e) {
        y = e.clientY - startY;
        x = e.clientX - startX;
        setPosition();
        if (drag) drag(e);
      }

      // Unbind drag events
      function mouseup(e) {
        $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
        if (stop) stop(e);
      }

      // Move element, within container if provided
      function setPosition() {
        if (container) {
          if (x < container.left) {
            x = container.left;
          } else if (x > container.right - width) {
            x = container.right - width;
          }
          if (y < container.top) {
            y = container.top;
          } else if (y > container.bottom - height) {
            y = container.bottom - height;
          }
        }

        elem.css({
          top: y + 'px',
          left:  x + 'px'
        });
      }
    }
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

When using absolute positioning you can center an element using `top: 50%; left: 50%;` and then move back the element by the half of its width:

That way, it doesn't matter how big or small the parent container is – the `.shape` will always be centered.

```
.shape {
    position: absolute;
    width : 40px;
    height: 40px;

    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;

    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;

    background-color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/5/

Comment: That doesn't work - it interferes with the behavior of the draggable directive.

Comment: @Oliver This is a perfect valid solution to center an absolute positioned element using CSS. The initial state is fine so far. Maybe the JS needs some more love…

Comment: it's a perfect valid solution for some other question.

Comment: @Oliver “ What should be the right code to get the white square to appear at the centre?” ??

Comment: I edited my own answer to show how it's done using `calc`.