# How to make this square appear at specified X,Y coordinates when page loads up?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

On this jsfiddle below, the square always appear at the top upper-left hand corner when the page loads.

http://jsfiddle.net/helpme128/3kwwo53t/2/

What if I have specified x, y coordinates that I want the element to appear during page load-up?

Suppose I have these dummy functions;

```
function getX() 
{
    return 145;
}

function getY()
{
    return 125;
}
```

How do I use the above 2 dummy functions and modify the jsfiddle to make the white square appear at the designated x,y coordinates returned by `getX()` and `getY()`? In the actual code, the dummy functions retrieve the x,y coordinates from some backend system.

This question is actually a follow-up question to [How to make this white square appear at centre by default instead of top upper-left hand corner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883553/how-to-make-this-white-square-appear-at-centre-by-default-instead-of-top-upper-l)

The answers provided involve modifying css. However, I am using AngularJS and I don't think angularjs can be used on css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

I feel you need to set the values from the `scope` you are passing from the `controller` and read those values to set the position of the shape.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

    .directive('ngDraggable', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            dragOptions: '=ngDraggable'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            var startX, startY, x = 0,
                y = 0,
                start, stop, drag, container;

            var width = elem[0].offsetWidth,
                height = elem[0].offsetHeight;

            // Obtain drag options
            if (scope.dragOptions) {
                start = scope.dragOptions.start;
                drag = scope.dragOptions.drag;
                stop = scope.dragOptions.stop;
                var id = scope.dragOptions.container;
                if (id) {
                    container = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
                }
                (function setInitPosition() {
                    x = scope.dragOptions.startX;
                    y = scope.dragOptions.startY;
                    setPosition();
                })();
            }
            // Bind mousedown event
            elem.on('mousedown', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                startX = e.clientX - elem[0].offsetLeft;
                startY = e.clientY - elem[0].offsetTop;
                $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
                if (start) start(e);
            });

            // Handle drag event
            function mousemove(e) {
                y = e.clientY - startY;
                x = e.clientX - startX;
                setPosition();
                if (drag) drag(e);
            }

            // Unbind drag events
            function mouseup(e) {
                $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
                if (stop) stop(e);
            }

            // Move element, within container if provided
            function setPosition() {
                if (container) {
                    if (x < container.left) {
                        x = container.left;
                    } else if (x > container.right - width) {
                        x = container.right - width;
                    }
                    if (y < container.top) {
                        y = container.top;
                    } else if (y > container.bottom - height) {
                        y = container.bottom - height;
                    }
                }

                elem.css({
                    top: y + 'px',
                    left: x + 'px'
                });
            }
        }
    }

})

    .controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var boundingRect = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect();
        var shapeRect = document.getElementsByClassName('shape')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    $scope.dragOptions = {
        start: function (e) {
            console.log("STARTING");
        },
        drag: function (e) {
            console.log("DRAGGING");
        },
        stop: function (e) {
            console.log("STOPPING");
        },
        startX: (boundingRect['width'] / 2) - (shapeRect['width'] / 2),
        startY: (boundingRect['height'] / 2) - (shapeRect['height'] / 2),
        container: 'container'
    }

});
```

```css
#container {
    width : 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: black;
}
.shape {
    position: absolute;
    width : 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="shape" ng-draggable='dragOptions'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/12/)

Comment: Great work! Seems like the only changes made were `startX: 150,
        startY: 150,` in the controller? Is that correct?

Comment: And `setInitPosition` in the directive to read and set the position. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. One thing puzzles me. I don't see anywhere in the code that calls setInitPosition(). How is it being called?

Comment: Its an `self executing` function. Also see the edit to place **shape** in the center.

Comment: Thanks again for the self-executing function. It is something new to me. What is the advantage of using self-executing function in this context versus just running the code?

Comment: No advantage in this particular case, I just wanted to differentiate that block of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91363/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-user768421).

Answer (score 1):

Use `elem` to add CSS proprieties via Javascript.

```
  function rand() {
      return Math.random() * 200;
  }

  elem.css({
      top: rand() + 'px',
      left: rand() + 'px'
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/11/

Comment: Thanks. But if I use css, the coordinates are hard-coded. Suppose I have 2 functions (getX(), getY) as mentioned in the question that will return the x, y coordinates dynamically. How can the code be written?

Comment: You can make use of the elem and add proprieties to him http://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/11/

Answer (score 1):

What about just setting the the positioning on the .shape in the css?
i.e. (in this case?).

```
top: 130px;
left: 130px;
```

Edit, I see it's the same answer as in your other question. Of course Angular can be used with CSS though, why not?

If you want to do it programatically you could check out the angular.element.css() function.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element